# Asking multiple numerical questions in a single post

Tags: discussion, etiquette

If I have three to four *numerical* questions based on the same topic (like logarithms or linear inequations, which mostly involve algebraic manipulations), can I put them in a single post, showing my efforts after each problem? Or should I put them separately in different posts?

Comment: If it is the same topic, one would hope that a detailed answer to one question would be enough to help OP with related questions. My feeling is that multiple questions decrease the chance of the question being answered. Also, even if the multiple questions are answered, the solutions are likely to be more mechanical, less informative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That the questions are on closely related topics does not change the fact that SE software does not work well with multiple questions posed in one post. For example, consider the following issues.

- Suppose a post contains a correct answer for one question but an incorrect answer for another. How should readers vote on the answer?
- How do you choose which answer to accept if the answers you like for each particular question are not in the same post?
- Duplicate handling becomes complicated: some questions may be dupes while others are not.
- Suppose that all but one of the questions is answered, but the last question is difficult and remains unanswered for a long time. Then users browsing the unanswered question list may have to expend much extra effort to answer the remaining question, since they'll have to browse through all of the answers to the other questions simply to infer which one remains unanswered (in contrast to a single question,  where that process is immediate). They may balk at the additional effort required, thus reducing the chance of obtaining an answer.

Answer (score 5):

My own general view is that the only time it makes sense to ask multiple questions in one post is if they share a long set-up:

> Let foo be a blah such that blah blah and blah. Let bar be a whatsit such that yadda yadda yadda. Suppose that for each baz mumble foo, there is a quux mumble bar such that etc., etc., etc.
>
> 1. Is blah blah blah true of foo?
> 2. Is whatever true of quux and baz?
> 3. etc.

If they're just three questions about a similar topic, rather than a similar *situation* or *object*, then ask them separately, and preferably one at a time, so you can try each again after you have digested each answer.

Comment: I think you have a typo.

Comment: @DanielRust, can you be more specific, or are you joking?

Comment: Yes, haha. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This is broad. Are they connected somewhat to each other, intuitively? If they involve different methods of problem solving, I suggest they belong in a separate post. Especially if they are long - stick to two tops, it will make the answer appear cleaner, less tedious to read for other users.